# Masked a external URL and redirection plugin

Tags: redirect

Hi and Merry Christmas,

Does anyone know what plugins that can be used to achieve this example below (basically it masked an external link and then redirect to the actual site)?

https://thepointsguy.com/apply/the-platinum-card-from-american-express/?tid=FAV-CARD-ALL-CARDS-2

Click on any of the cards image: https://thepointsguy.com/cards/ and you can see it in action.

Appreciate any help/advice!

Thanks in advance,
yeeloon